# При переходе на site.ru должен перекидывать на site.ru/index.php

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как сделать?

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?cstart=$1 [L]
```

не катит!

Нужно, чтобы прописывался index.php.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
Redirect permanent / /index.php
```

Comment: Я чуть неправильно сказал путь...

`site.ru/panel2/` нужно на `site.ru/panel2/index.php`, что-то не получается поменять

Comment: Тогда проще так сделать: DirectoryIndex index.php